# Making multiple commands appear on the same output line

Tags: bash

Hi I keep having trouble with this

```
echo 'Welcome to my first Script'
mkdir myScript
cd myScript
touch doc1 sales.doc.test2.txt outline.doc

echo 'You now have ' ;find . -type f|wc -l;echo 'files in your "myScript" folder'

address="205"
echo -n "Please enter your favourite number:"
read myvar
echo "The number you entered is $myvar"
```

I'm trying to make the output say "You now have (3) files in your myScript folder" as one line, but it keeps outputting them on 3 seperate lines. I've tried 3 or 4 different codes here (by clicking the similar questions above) but they give me funny errors and this is just my first script, so I understand all the commands I'm using (minus the calculation for files, I had to google that one).

Answer (score 7):

`echo "You now have $(find . -type f|wc -l ) files in your \"myScript\" folder"`

Additionally, I'd recommend altering the `find` to include `-maxdepth 1`, otherwise you'll recurse...

Comment: +1 but don't forget to escape the inner quotes so they'll show up in the output

Answer (score 3):

They are on separate lines because `echo` and `wc` output newlines.

One way around it is this:

```
echo 'You now have' $(find . -type f | wc -l) 'files in your "myScript" folder'
```

Here we get rid of extra `echo` newline because we use one `echo` to rule them all. We get rid of `wc` newline because with this kind of substitution, the output of `wc` is broken into words and those words are passed to `echo` as separate arguments; word separators are lost (echo uses space to separate its arguments on output).

Answer (score 2):

Use the no-new-line switch `-n` and echo the result of your `find`:

```
echo -n 'You now have ' ; echo -n "`find . -type f|wc -l`"; echo -n ' files in your "myScript" folder'
```

Comment: It's a pity that `wc` has no no-new-line switch.

Comment: Yeah... just realized that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `printf` command:

```
printf 'You now have %d files in your "myScript" folder' $( find . -type f | wc -l )
```

(A slight variation on the other answers using command substitution embedded in the string.)